# Best way for add spacing between and around ASCellNode in ASTableNode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, asyncdisplaykit

I`m using AsyncDisplayKit for dev my ios app and using ASTableNode.
What is best way for add spacing between ASCellNode in ASTableNode ?
I want to make it look something like this:

[image]

My ideas on how to do this:

1. set the frame size of ASCellNode?
   Minus ideas: how to be if height of cell different?
2. add a subNode and set its size smaller, given the indentation?
   Minus ideas: extra element
3. add header like in UITableView, but how add left and right margin ?

Can eat other decision?
Is there a way using AsyncDisplayKit?

And another related question, is it possible to add a shadow between the cells, as in the picture?

Comment: Best way from my point of view is you have to complete using design only no code require, Means leave spacing in your Cell

Answer (score 0):

Use ASInsetLayoutSpec, as shown in the example code:
https://github.com/facebook/AsyncDisplayKit/blob/a64253cf38df57120ed0ef80edf45b8521b02d13/examples_extra/Shop/Shop/Scenes/Shop/ShopCellNode.swift